# Обновление части страницы

Tags: ajax, javascript, php

Собственно проблема: есть index.php, который выводит странички. Делаются вставки в хтмл вида `<div id="content"><?=$content?></div>`. Вот нужно обновлять один такой `<div>` без обновления всей страницы. Использовал бы готовый пример на AJAX, но проблема в том, что у меня все данные передаются в виде `?act=clients&sub_id=cli_all` и заодно формы отсылают еще поля вида hidden, то есть всё приходит в этот же index.php, а все примеры с AJAX подразумевают вызов стороннего скрипта php. Вопрос - как реализовать в таких условия обновления `<div>` с периодичностью скажем 5 секунд?

Comment: "*у меня все данные передаются в виде*" - передаются в обработчик, который вытаскивает данные из базы? Тогда, что вас смущает во фразе: "*примеры с AJAX подразумевают вызов стороннего скрипта php*"? Это ведь тот же самый обработчик.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самый простой способ: с помощью jQuery слать post-запросы на `index.php?act=clients&sub_id=cli_all`**&ajax**, а в индексном файле проверять: если есть параметр `$_GET['ajax']`, то отдавать только контентную часть. Примерный javascript-код:

```
(function(){
    var data = $('input[name="data"]').val();
    var update = arguments.callee;
    $.post('index.php?act=clients&sub_id=cli_all&ajax', {'data': data}, function(txt){
        $('#content').html(txt);
        setTimeout(update, 5000);
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function upd(txt){
 var divobj=document.getElementById("content");
 divobj.innerHTML=txt;
}
var interval=setInterval("upd('Новое содержимое #div')",5000);
```

Если ответ не в тему не минусуйте пожалуйста а просто скажите и я удалю!